# Fitting mixture model of different distributions in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I have some data $X$ which seems to consist of two different subpopulations, one following a Gamma and one following a Normal distribution. Therefore I'd like to model this as a mixture model consisting of said distributions, but I don't know how to fit this in R. I'd prefer to estimate the model using maximum-likelihood or the EM-algorithm, but something else would be nice too. There are numerous packages for doing this for mixtures consisting out of only Gaussians or Poissons etc. But I can't find anything for mixed models consisting of more than one distribution family, and I'm also kind of a novice to R so I wouldn't know how to implement this myself. Help would be greatly appreciated!